# Explicit formula for the adjoint of the derivation operation?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

**MY NOTATIONS**. $\mathcal{P}_3(\mathbb{R})$ is the vector space of all polynomials with real coefficients up to degree 3. $D^*$ is the adjoint operator of $D$ defined as the unique (since $\mathcal{P}_3(\mathbb{R})$ has finite dimension) operator that satisfies $\forall p,q \in \mathcal{P}_3(\mathbb{R}) \ \langle Dp,q \rangle =\langle p,D^*q \rangle$.

**THE PROBLEM**. Consider in $\mathcal{P}_3(\mathbb{R})$ the inner product

$$\langle p,q \rangle =\int_0^1 p(x)q(x) \ dx$$

and let $D$ be the derivation operator over $\mathcal{P}_3(\mathbb{R})$. Find $D^*$.

**MY IDEAS**. I know I can solve this by appealing to a orthonormal basis of $\mathcal{P}_3(\mathbb{R})$. If $\mathcal{B}=\{ v_1,...,v_4 \}$ is one of this kind, then $\forall p \in \mathcal{P}_3(\mathbb{R})$

$$ D^*=\sum_{i=1}^4  \langle Dv_i, p \rangle v_i$$

(where I used some known propositions and the fact that $\mathcal{P}_3(\mathbb{R})$ is a real vector space). Besides the fact that determining orthonormal basis is always rather boring, I find this approach exceedingly complicated. My professor gave me a hint that it is possible to work a solution using only the definition of adjoint operators – something I couldn’t manage to do. I tried to work with general polynomials $p$ and $q$ and the given inner product, but got nowhere. Does anyone has some idea to share?

Comment: I bet the hint is suggesting that you should integrate by parts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By integration by parts, we get:
$$\int_0^1 (D^* f)(x) g(x) \, dx = \int_0^1 f(x) g'(x) \, dx = f(1) g(1) - f(0) g(0) - \int_0^1 f'(x) g(x) \, dx.$$

So, the last term gives a contribution of $-f'$ to $D^* f$.  For the other terms, you need to find $a$ and $b$ such that $\langle a, g \rangle = g(1)$ and $\langle b, g \rangle = g(0)$ for all $g \in \mathcal{P}_3(\mathbb{R})$, and then $D^*f = f(1) a - f(0) b - f'$.  (Note that the condition on $b$ is equivalent to $\langle b, x^i \rangle = \delta_{i, 0}$ for $i=0,1,2,3$, and then by symmetry $a(x) = -b(1-x)$.)

Comment: I tried something like this earlier, but the problem is to specify such $a,b \in \mathcal{P}_3(\mathbb{R})$. It is clear that they exist and are unique (by the Riesz representation theorem). The "procedure" I know to determine them depends on a orthonormal basis though. Can you imagine any other way around? 

I didn't understand how to follow from your final remark.

Comment: Suppose that $b = b_0 + b_1 x + b_2 x^2 + b_3 x^3$; then you need to solve the system of equations $b_0 + \frac{1}{2} b_1 + \frac{1}{3} b_2 + \frac{1}{4} b_3 = 1$, $\frac{1}{2} b_0 + \frac{1}{3} b_1 + \frac{1}{4} b_2 + \frac{1}{5} b_3 = 0$, etc.  Admittedly still leaves a lot of tedious computation...